# Create tester program to record the frequency of rolls on a die?

Tags: java, dice

I need to make a class that has a public method `roll()` which will return a random int between 1 and 6. Then I need to make a tester program that measures the frequency of rolls meaning it counts up how many ones, twos, threes, etc. in 1000 rolls.

My die class is as below:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Die {

  public int roll() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int n = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    return n;
  }
}
```

and this is my tester class:

```
public class DieTester extends Die {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ones = 0;
    int twos = 0;
    int threes = 0;
    int fours = 0;
    int fives = 0;
    int sixes = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      int roll();
      if(n == 1) {
        ones = ones + 1;
      }
      if(n == 2) {
        twos = twos + 1;
      }
      if(n == 3) {
        threes = threes + 1;
      }
      if(n == 4) {
        fours = fours + 1;
      }
      if(n == 5) {
        fives = fives + 1;
      }
      if(n == 6) {
        sixes = sixes + 1;
      }
    }

    System.out.println(ones);
    System.out.println(twos);
    System.out.println(threes);
    System.out.println(fours);
    System.out.println(fives);
    System.out.println(sixes);
  }
}
```

However the `int roll();` function in the Die Tester class is not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you say it's not working?

Comment: You forgot to create an Instance of `Die`, call `roll()` on it and store that in `int n`.

Comment: `int roll();` isn't a valid statement. Neither is `roll(n);`. I think you mean `int n = roll();`.

Comment: @luk2302 The tester extends `Die`.

Comment: but the call happens is in a static context, `roll()` is not static @shmosel.

Comment: I did that but now it says this

Comment: DieTester.java:12: error: non-static method roll() cannot be referenced from a static context
          int n = roll();
                  ^
1 error

Comment: @luk2302 Good point, missed that.

Comment: `roll(n);` is not valid because your `roll()` method does not take any parameters and you did not create any variable called `n` before trying to call the method.

Comment: It would be best to make `rand` a field instead of reinitializing it on every call.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:

- `int roll();` is not a valid statement in its current place
- *if* you want to keep `roll` the way it is you need to create an instance of `Die` first, otherwise make it `static`

---

Solution using `static`

```
public class Die {
    public static int roll() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        return n;
    }
}

public class DieTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // variables

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            int n = Die.roll();
            // your if logic
        }

        // printing
    }
}
```

---

Solution using an instance of `Die`

```
public class Die {
    public int roll() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        return n;
    }
}

public class DieTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // variables
        Die die = new Die();

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            int n = die.roll();
            // your if logic
        }

        // printing
    }
}
```

---

In both cases it does not make *much* sense to make `DieTester` `extend` `Die`.

Answer (score 0):

[luk2302's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48694112/7694740) is correct. I think is worth to mention that you can do this a lot easier with [`Random::ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-):

```
Map<Integer, Long> dieTest = new Random().ints(1000,1,7) // generate 1000 pseudorandom values from 1 to 6
        .boxed()                                         // box each int to Integer
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())); // group by each distinct value counting the number of its occurrence in the stream

System.out.println(dieTest);
```

Sample output showing the frequency of each number:

> {1=178, 2=158, 3=165, 4=154, 5=183, 6=162}